# WordPress images not displaying after uploading and importing wordpress.xml file

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently facing a problem with my with my Wordpress site. While setting up my theme, when I uploaded the Wordpress.xml file, I got a long list of these Fails.

```
Failed to import shop_order_status cancelled
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status cancelled
Failed to import shop_order_status cancelled
Failed to import shop_order_status cancelled
Failed to import shop_order_status cancelled
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
Failed to import shop_order_status cancelled
Failed to import shop_order_status on-hold
```

And after that my page looks like this

[image]

Kindly respond if you have any solution or workaround for this.

Comment: check this [Import media to online WordPress from local development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/87407/12615)

Comment: Have you checked your server time-out setting? It#s highly likely that the import is failing due to it taking too long and the server kills the process.